# How can I display a contact form after a video ends on my website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

`<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementsByClassName('hideVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false); function myHandler(e) { var hideVideo = document.getElementsByClassName("hideVideo")[0]; hideVideo.style.display = "none"; } </script>`

I'm creating a website where only 1 video is shown on the entire page. What I want is after the video ends, contact form should come as a pop up and the video should disappear. How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far, we can't code for you, we can help you refactor your code in the right way. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will with what you want to do:

```
<video id="sample-video" style="max-width:100%;width:100%;" controls="">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="myForm">
  Add your form here
</div>
```

```
var v = document.getElementById('sample-video');
v.play();
v.addEventListener('ended', function () { 
  var formDiv = document.getElementById("myForm");
  if (formDiv.style.display === "none") {
    formDiv..style.display = "block";
  } else {
    formDiv..style.display = "none";
  }
},false);
```

This is the [source](https://frontbackend.com/javascript/how-to-fire-an-event-when-html5-video-finishes)

Comment: How can I trigger the form can you please help me out

Comment: @AyushYelne I updated the answer, I hope this is more clear like this

Answer (score 0):

You can find there what you need about html video element events and more.

[HTML Audio/Video Properties](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var videoObj = document.getElementById('sample-video');
videoObj .play();
videoObj .addEventListener('ended', function () { 
document.getElementById("form-id").style.display="block";
this.style.display = "none";
},false);
```

```css
#form-id{
display : none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<video id="sample-video" style="max-width:100%;width:100%;" controls="">
    <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2015-09/large_watermarked/Search_Google_preview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
<div>
<form id="form-id">
<h1>Your form</h1>
<label>Form Field 1</label>
<input type="text">
<label>Form Field 2</label>
<input type="text">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Call to Action

When reviewing the example below:

1. wait 5 seconds for the `<video>` to end
2. a `<dialog>` with a `<form>` will open
3. enter the required data and submit it
4. data will be submitted to a live test server
5. the `<dialog>` will close
6. an `<iframe>`<sup>✺</sup> will appear under the `<video>` with the server response
   <sup>✺Not required -- only added for example</sup>

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <video>, <dialog>, and <form>
const vid = document.querySelector('video');
const mod = document.querySelector('dialog');
const con = document.forms[0];
// Bind the 'ended' event to <video>
vid.onended = cta;
/*
Event handler passes Event Object by default
Hide, pause, and reset <video>
Open <dialog>
*/
function cta(e) {
  vid.style.display = 'none';
  vid.pause();
  vid.currentTime = 0;
  mod.showModal();
}

// Bind 'click' and 'submit' events to <form>
con.onclick = close;
con.onsubmit = close;

/*
If the user clicked .close OR <form> is submitted...
...close <dialog>...
...show <video> and add controls
*/
function close(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.close') || e.type === 'submit') {
    mod.close();
    vid.style.display = 'block';
    vid.controls = true;
  }
}

// This was added so you don't have to sit and wait for the whole video to end
vid.ontimeupdate = quit;

function quit(e) {
  if (this.currentTime >= 5) {
    this.currentTime = this.duration;
  }
};
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

video {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto 10px;
}

dialog {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.2rem
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font: inherit;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::before {
  content: attr(value);
}

#close {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin: -12px 0 0 4px;
  padding: 0 1px 3px;
  outline: 0;
}

sup {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  color: red;
}

input+sup {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -8px 0 1px;
}

small+sup,
small {
  float: right;
}

small {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<video src='https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs12s3.mp4' width='240' autoplay muted></video>
<dialog>
  <form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
    <button id='close' class='close' type='button' value='x'></button>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Subscribe</legend>
      <input name='user' type='text' placeholder='User Name' required><sup>✱</sup><br>
      <input name='email' type='email' placeholder='Email Address' required><sup>✱</sup><br>
      <button value='Submit'></button>
      <button class='close' type='button' value='Cancel'></button>
    </fieldset>
    <small>Required</small><sup>✱</sup>
  </form>
</dialog>
<iframe name='response' width='240'></iframe>
```